# pasar un array de c# a c++

Tags: c#, c++, unity

Estoy utilizando código nativo en `c#.` estoy intentado pasar un array de c# a `C++` utilizando `Pinvoke`. Una vez en `C++`, quiero llenar ese array que he pasado como parámetro con los valores de un `cv::Mat.`

El problema es que estoy usando la función **copy** y no creo que este pasando bien los parámetros.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? un saludo y gracias

**MI CODIGO DE C++ :**

```
__declspec(dllexport)
void video(unsigned char* arr) {
Mat frame;
Mat resi;
Mat dst;//dst image
camera >> frame;
if (frame.empty()) {
    return;
}
flip(frame, dst,1);
//resize(dst, resi, Size(width, height));
cv::cvtColor(dst, dst, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
copy(dst.datastart, dst.dataend, arr);
}
```

**MI CÓDIGO DE C#:**

```
 [DllImport("NativoPrincipio")]
 public static extern void video(byte[] img);

 imgData = new byte[width * height* 4];
 video(imgData);
```

Comment: ya se es una idea parecida, pero necesito implementarlo ahora de esta manera. utilizando el copy y pasando el array como parametro

Comment: se que la funcion que estoy utlizando mas es el copy, pero como nunca lo he usado, no se.....

Comment: A ver, lo primero creo que el parametro en c# no es necesario que sea `out`. Por otro, prueba en el lado c# con `memcpy(arr, frame, tam);` en lugar del `copy`. Y por ultimo, si no te funciona especifica exactamente que es lo que pasa (error,datos incorrectos,etc..)

Comment: O quizá `memcpy(arr, frame.data, tam);`

Comment: he probado con memcpy y no me hace nada, es mas unity se pada y se cierra

Comment: Quitaste `out` como te dije? : `[DllImport("NativoPrincipio.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] public static extern void ProcessFrame( byte[] img);`

Comment: si, y me devuelve esto. UnityException: LoadRawTextureData: not enough data provided. dado que el codigo sigue así:

            `byte[] imgData = new byte[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
            ProcessFrame(imgData);

            Debug.Log(imgData.Length);
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            tex.LoadRawTextureData(imgData);
            tex.Apply();
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;`

Comment: Ahi no puedo ayudarte mas, ya que no se de Unity. Yo tengo un ejemplo hecho que me funciona perfectamente. Deberías primero depurar para ver si en `imgData` estas recibiendo los datos correctamente. Por otro lado,buscando el error, sugieren añadir `TextureFormat.RGBA32, false`...

Comment: estoy intentando utilizar la funcion de std::copy para pasa el dato de cv::mat a uchar*. el problema es que se me cierra el programa al ejecutarlo. 

__declspec(dllexport)
void ProcessFrame(unsigned char* arr, int width, int height) {
      VideoCapture camera;
 if (!camera.open(0))
 {
  return;
 }
 Mat frame;
 camera >> frame;
 if (frame.empty()) {
  return;
 }
 copy(frame.datastart, frame.dataend, arr);
}

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz deberías asegurarte que las dimensiones de `webcamTexture` y `frame` son iguales... o eso o cambia la firma de la función para que `ProcessFrame` acepte un puntero doble... así podrás inicializar `arr` en la propia función (acuérdate entonces de liberar la memoria en la parte C#

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: mira en el enunciado que lo he corregido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
[DllImport("NativoPrincipio")]
public static extern void video(IntPtr img);

byte[] getVideo(int width, int height)
{
   var imgData = new byte[width * height * 4];
   GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(imgData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   video(h.AddrOfPinnedObject());
   return imgData;
}
```

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, pero tu respuesta estaría mucho mas completa si explicas a OP que es lo que hace tu código y como soluciona su problema, te invito a revisar [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y como no también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). ;)